# Composer dump-autoload does not update the autoload_namespace.php in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

When installing new packages in Laravel 5.2, even with the package has been downloaded and successfully installed, to add the provider in `app.php`, publish and run the composer `dump-autoload`, the provider is given as not found.

What has been done:

- Written permission in the vendor folder and vendor / composer folder;
- `Composer dump-autoload` (numerous times and all variations);
- Re-installation of the package;
- Installation of the packages in a fresh version;

> **Important Notes:** ran the composer update before placing the provider
>   folder and ran the publish and `dump-autoload` after adding the
>   provider. Yes, it was working at some time, have other packages
>   already installed. The package is being installed normally, but the
>   composer is not adding in `autoload_namespaces.php`. Even in
>   `classmap` they appear.

If anyone can help me I will be grateful.